# Is it possible to support an SPA/Ajax Login Form for an Authenticator in Keycloak?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, keycloak, keycloak-services, redhat-sso

We would like to build an SPA-like login form in Keycloak, which would dynamically show prompts for credential/inputs from the user without having to refresh the page.

From what I can see, each Authenticator in Keycloak is expecting a form-POST on its associated view, from which it extracts the response. So by default, this implies that each implementation of Authenticator SPI we would like to support (e.g. username/password, 2fa, security questions, etc) would require a page refresh to collect the user's input.

Is there any way an SPA-like login experience (with multiple Authenticators) can be achieved with Keycloak? Any thoughts/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can try to exploit 'direct grant' flow. But in this case you are gonna miss SSO features, like autologin after opening different applications. Keycloak SSO features based on work with cookies (http only).

Comment: Thanks @solveMe for the reply. As you already know, direct grant flow isn't recommended from a security perspective, so we probably wouldn't want to go that route. And the auto-login part is actually essential for our SSO solution. If the user had to login to each individual app, it would be a shower-stopper.